# First applet - Null Point Exception in browser?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I know this question is probably asked a TON, but from what I understand it's pretty situational and nothing I've tried so far has worked.

I'm making a basic applet that simply needs to have an image and a simple function. Mine in particular gives a random quote of Dwight from "The Office" when a user hits the button (Later on their text input will have some sort of say in how the quote is determined).

My problem here though is the applet runs in my JGrasp, but doesn't run in the browser from a local file. The code is basically complete, but can anyone help me pinpoint where it's going wrong? I just don't really understand how it can work in my applet viewer but not my browser, it's odd. I tried switching over my SWING to AWT, but it didn't seem to help, so I used my older version.

I'm posting my code, HTML file and results from the java console when the applet failed. at the moment I'm still trying to figure out what exactly to print from the java console, but figured I'd post this regardless in the meantime. Thanks for any and all help!

```
// Imports
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;    
import javax.swing.*;   
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java 

public class AskDwight extends JApplet {

   // initialize GUI components
   private JPanel panel;
   private JLabel questionLabel, responseLabel;
   private JButton askButton;
   private JTextField questionField;

   // Constructor
   public void init()
   {
      buildGUI();
      // Add panel to content pane
      add(panel);  
   }

   // buildPanel method adds components to GUI
   private void buildGUI()
   {
      questionLabel = new JLabel("Question :");
      questionField = new JTextField(35);
      askButton = new JButton("Ask!");
      java.net.URL imageURL = AskDwight.class.getResource("dwight.PNG");
      JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
      imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageURL));
      askButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 30));

      // Response label builder
      responseLabel = new JLabel("");
      responseLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
      responseLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      responseLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

      // Add an action listener to the button
      askButton.addActionListener(new AskButtonListener());

      // Create panels
      panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

      // Add components to the panels
      panel.add(questionLabel);
      panel.add(questionField);
      panel.add(askButton);
      panel.add(imageLabel);
      panel.add(responseLabel);   
   }

   // Action Listener class for the ask button
   private class AskButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      // Ask method exectutes when the button is clicked
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         String inputQuestion;                 // Holds user's input question
         String[] response = new String[10];  // Holds Dwight's random responses
         String randomResponse;

         // Dwight Responses - contained in String array
         response[0] = "<html>Fact: You can use the molten goose grease and save "
                        + "it in the refrigerator.</html>";
         response[1] = "<html>False: Bears do not eat beats.</html>";
         response[2] = "<html>Question: Do you ever stop asking stupid questions?</html>";
         response[3] = "<html>Fact: Bears can climb faster than they can run.</html>";
         response[4] = "<html>What are you even asking? I order you to Cease and "
                       + "desist right now, as third in command</html>.";
         response[5] = "<html>You think that's funny? Millions suffer every year at "
                       + "the expense of your jokes.</html>.";
         response[6] = "<html>MICHAEL!";
         response[7] = "<html>A day on Schrute's beet farm would shut your mouth.</html>";
         response[8] = "<html>False: Nothing you say is important.</html>";
         response[9] = "<html>I always keep concealed pepper spray just for an "
                       + "occasion such as this.</html>";

         // inputQuestion gets the user's entered string
         inputQuestion = questionField.getText();

         // When button is pressed, the following code will select
         // a random response from the string array
         Random rand = new Random();
         randomResponse = response [rand.nextInt(response.length)];
         responseLabel.setText(randomResponse);

      }
   }  

}
```

Here's the HTML code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Ask Dwight Schrute</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<applet code="AskDwight.class" width="420" height ="500">
</applet>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Where is the `NullPointerException`? Also, it's not _really_ situational. You will get a `NullPointerException` when you're trying to reference something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You expect us to be able to help you without an error message?

Comment: @CanadianDavid No NPE when runnning locally, NPE in applet.

Comment: You're loading the class off the Server, not the Jar file, so `AskDwight.class.getResource("dwight.PNG")` isn't going to work, as the applet classloader won't be able to find the resource

Comment: I'm currently working on getting the stack trace, I'm new to the Java console/applets. I figured I may as well just post what I have so far until I figure it out, just to see if someone could spot it before I found it. Also @MatProgrammer, I had this in a different format but then I was getting an error with the image. I tried this based on what my professor told me, but I guess there might still be something wrong with it...

Comment: Just another quick thing: The null pointer exception message came from the applet in the browser when I clicked it. It then gave me the option to pull up the java console (Which I'm still trying to get the stack trace from at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified the programs class, but not provide the applications archive, this means that any call to `Class#getResource` is going to fail as the applet's classloader has no concept about where those resources might be stored, instead, consider trying something like...

```
<applet code = 'AskDwight' 
    archive = 'AskDwight.jar'
    width = 420
    height = 500>
</applet>
```

Assuming you've built the project into a `Jar` and have it deployed on the server...

It's been a (very) long time since I've done any applet program, so this might be slightly off...

Take a closer look at [Deploying an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) for more details

**Updated based on feedback**

If you can't use a Jar file then you'll need to use, something like `Image img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "dwight.PNG");` to load the image...

The image will need to stored in the same location as your class files, for example, if `AskDwight.class` doesn't belong to a package, they would reside at the same location (on the drive). If `AskDwight.class` belonged to the `com.foo.bar` package, the image file would be in the directory above `com`

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately it can't be put into a jar as per the assignment requirements, as we have to turn in a java file. It's also ran from my local files directly onto a browser, but I'll see if this can still work somehow

Comment: Then you need to tell the applet to load the image from server, something like `Image img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "dwight.PNG");` for example.  The image need to placed at the same location as the classes (at the top of the package structure I believe)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit naive about this. When you say top of the package structure, do you refer to where my imported java components like SWING are and my public class? I'll look into how to put it there and reference it if that's the case

Comment: What I mean is, where you place `AskDwight.class`, the image(s) should be placed at the top level of that directory based on the `package` requirements of `AskDwight.class`, so if `AskDwight.class` doesn't belong to a `package`, they would reside at the same location (on the drive). If `AskDwight.class` belonged to the `com.foo.bar` package, the image file would be in the directory above `com`